# Order LINQ by "string" name

Tags: linq, string, sql-order-by

**PROBLEM SOLVED!!!**

The solution is Linq.Dynamic

You do it like this:

```
(from c in Context.AccountCharts 
    where c.Account_FK == account && c.Year_FK == year select c).OrderBy(order);
```

You have to download the **System.Linq.Dynamic.dll** and include it into your project.

---

Is there a way to order a linq query by the name of a field. like this:

```
from c in Context.AccountCharts 
    where c.Account_FK == account && c.Year_FK == year 
    orderby c["ColName"] select c;
```

Or

```
from c in Context.AccountCharts 
    where c.Account_FK == account && c.Year_FK == year 
    orderby c.GetType().GetField("ColName") select c;
```

None of these two works but I hope you know of a way to do this.

Comment: You want to sort the entire table, based a field which can change row-by-row?  that is, if ColName is "Account_FK" in the first row, and "Year" is the second row, by which column do you wish to sort it?

Comment: So you're trying to use reflection inside a LINQ query? What happens if you go for `orderby c.GetType().GetField("ColName").GetValue(c)`?

Comment: @James, @Anon, I think he simply wants the `orderby` to be variable rather than hardcoded. So in one case, he wants to sort on ColumnA, another ColumnB, and would rather not write multiple functions that differ only on the `orderby` line. If so, his use of the term `field` is unfortunate, since that implies a private member variable rather than a column in a database.

Comment: if i use the GetField("ColName") i get: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot order by type 'System.Reflection.FieldInfo'

Comment: @Skinner: Did you include the `GetValue(c)` on the end, or not?

Comment: if i use c.GetType().GetField("No").GetValue(c) i get: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot order by type 'System.Object'. And if i cast it to string that i know ColName is i get: The argument 'value' was the wrong type. Expected 'System.String'. Actual 'System.Object'.

Answer (score 1):

I spend to many time to resolve this issue, but didn't find any better than:

```
var queryExpression;
if (c["ColName"]=="CreateDate")
    queryExpression.OrderBy(x => x.CreateDate);
```

Comment: Actually I believe that just wants to be `if (ColName=="CreateDate")`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work too though not tested

```
Context.AccountCharts.Where(c=>c.Account_FK == account && c.Year_FK == year).OrderBy(o=>o.order);
```